# Selenium Webdriver is not saving screenshots to directory

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot of a website using a Selenium Webdriver and save it at desired location.

The below code runs fine but Selenium does not save any screenshots for me?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

links = ['https://duckduckgo.com','https://google.com','https://facebook.com','https://reddit.com'];


browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/xxxx/Downloads/chromedriver.exe');
browser.maximize_window()

for x in links:


    browser.get(x)

    browser.save_screenshot("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Downloads\\website"+x+".png")
    print("website"+x+".png")

    time.sleep(2)
browser.close()
```

Does anyone know how I can get Selenium to take a screenshot and save it to my computer?

Comment: You could consider adding the webpage which you are using as reference and also check this tutorial here: https://pythonspot.com/selenium-take-screenshot/

Comment: I'm not familiar with selenium myself, but what does the documentation say about how this should be done and the expected outcome? Did you search online (e.g. see [this](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-take-screenshot/))? Did that code sample work for you?

Comment: Apparently [save_screenshot](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.save_screenshot) returns False if an error occurs. What does your save_screenshot call return?

Comment: Are you sure that `"website"+x+".png"` is a valid file name in your operating system? For example, `websitehttps://duckduckgo.com.png` would not be legal in Windows because Windows filenames can't contain colons or slashes.

Answer (score 0):

The file name you're trying to create is incorrect. You can use the following and it should work:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

links = ['https://duckduckgo.com','https://google.com','https://facebook.com','https://reddit.com'];
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/xxxx/Downloads/chromedriver.exe');
browser.maximize_window()

for x in links:
    browser.get(x)
    print(browser.save_screenshot("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Downloads\\" + x.split('//')[1].split('.')[0] + "_screenshot.png"))
    print("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Downloads\\" + x.split('//')[1].split('.')[0] + "_screenshot.png")
    time.sleep(2)
browser.close()

# >> C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Downloads\\duckduckgo_screenshot.png
# >> [User@Downloads ~] dir
# >> test.py duckduckgo_screenshot.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer. but why doesn't it throw any error like "invalid file" or something like that?

Comment: The `save_screenshot()` method returns false which is the expected behaviour